# Basic JScalc.io calculator trouble (Output variable blank, not returning a number)

Tags: javascript, calculator, drone.io

I am making a super basic JS calculator via [jscalc.io](http://jscalc.io)

I am having trouble with my variables. Here is [a link to my calculator](https://jscalc.io/calc/xfIKs4HJ017WjyoV).

The problem is just with the "GSD" output on the bottom right. I am not getting any syntax errors but GSD will not spit out a number... it's just blank? Is it because I am trying to make a function using outputs instead of inputs?

Hope someone can give any guidance.

Here is the relevant code with the formula for my GSD output variable:

```js
'use strict';
var meters = inputs.W * inputs.L
;var kilometers = meters * 0.000001
;var acres = meters * 0.000247105
;var hectares = meters * 0.0001
;var miles = acres * 0.0015625
;var H = H
;var GSD = (Sw * H * 100) / (Fr * imW);

//GSD = (Sw * H * 100) / (Fr * imW)

// DRONE CAMERA TYPE SETTINGS RESOLUTION
console.log(inputs.camera);
var imW;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'P3I1'){
imW = 4000;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var imH;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'P3I1'){
imH = 3000;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var imW;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'I1P'){
imW = 4608;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var imH;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'I1P'){
imH = 3456;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var imW;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'CS100'){
imW = 4000;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var imH;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'CS100'){
imH = 3000;
}

// DRONE CAMERA TYPE SETTINGS FOCAL LENGTH
console.log(inputs.camera);
var Fr;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'P3I1'){
Fr = 3.61;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var Fr;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'I1P'){
Fr = 15;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var Fr;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'CS100'){
Fr = 5.2;
}

// DRONE CAMERA TYPE SETTINGS PIXEL PITCH
console.log(inputs.camera);
var PP;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'P3I1'){
PP = 1.56;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var PP;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'I1P'){
PP = 4.8;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var PP;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'CS100'){
PP = 3.4;
}

// DRONE CAMERA TYPE SETTINGS SENSOR WIDTH
console.log(inputs.camera);
var Sw;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'P3I1'){
Sw = 6.24;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var Sw;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'I1P'){
Sw = 22.12;
}
console.log(inputs.camera);
var Sw;
if (inputs.camera.toString() === 'CS100'){
Sw = 13.6;
}

return {
  meters: meters,
  kilometers: kilometers,
  acres: acres,
  hectares: hectares,
  miles: miles,
  imW: imW,
  imH: imH,
  Fr: Fr,
  PP: PP,
  Sw: Sw,
  GSD: GSD,
  // imH: imH
};
```

Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the line `var H = H`, this ought to be `var H = inputs.H`